# How to create a shortcut/hotkey in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

i was trying out something in vb.net that when a user pressed Alt + W on their keyboard it will increment
a number on a text box, this is what i have done so far:

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim inc As Integer
    Dim out As String

    Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown

        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Alt AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.W Then
            inc = inc + 1
            TextBox1.Text = inc.ToString

       End If
End Sub
```

I tried searching even on youtube for answers and it always shows a shortcut keys for button click. I'm a total beginner in VB.net or even in programming. I apologize if this is a duplicate question, Thanks in advance.

Comment: `If e.KeyCode = Keys.Alt AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.W` - that is exactly the same as `If X = 1 AndAlso X = 2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, make sure that you have `KeyPreview` set to `True` for the form, or else it will not raise keyboard events when a control that does so (e.g. a `TextBox`) has focus.

As for detecting the desired keys, the `KeyCode` property is for the single key that was just depressed. If you want to detect a modifier key then there a number of different ways. One option is like so:

```vb
If e.Alt AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.W Then
```

That will detect whether the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key is depressed when you press the <kbd>W</kbd> key. The thing is though, that ignores the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> keys, so it would detect any modifier combination that included <kbd>Alt</kbd>. You could do this:

```vb
If e.Alt AndAlso Not e.Control AndAlso Not e.Shift AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.W Then
```

but that's unnecessarily verbose. A better option is the following:

```vb
If e.KeyData = (Keys.Alt Or Keys.W) Then
```

That will detect only <kbd>Alt+W</kbd>. `KeyData` is a combination of modifier keys and the key just depressed, so this will match a specific modifier combination and exclude all others.

Take note that it is the `Or` bitwise operator that is used to combine the `Keys` values. Intuition might lead yo to think that it should be `And` if you don't understand bitwise operators.

Note that a further option is like so:

```vb
If e.Modifiers = e.Alt AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.W then
```

You may find that clearer but the `KeyData` option is the most succinct.

Comment: I tried every option and it worked perfectly. Thank you so much! :D